# How to write and include regular ruby classes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Rails. I have a controller responsible for presenting data from parsing files uploaded by the user. I don't want the data to be stored anywhere in the model. Can I include a class that I can instantiate in my controller method? Here is a basic code example of what I mean:

This controller only contains one method:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def index
        test = FileProcessorService.new
        @test = test.test()
    end
end
```

Here is the class that will handle the logic when the instantiates calls its method:

```
class FileProcessorService
    def test
        return 'This is a test'
    end
end
```

My questions:

Where is the best place to store this class? How can I refer to this class in my controller? 
Any advice on this particular topic of using classes in rails? Are instances of a regular ruby class a problem in the controller? I dont want my users seeing the same data. Thats why I dont want to include global variables in my controller. No models since I have an MVC back ground with Java MVC. I'll move on to models once I understand how the basic rails controller functionality works.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually put these in `app/classes`, or if there are a lot of them, into more specific folders likes `app/services`, `app/notifiers`, etc.

You can enable autoloading in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/classes #{config.root}/app/services)
```

If they're not application-specific, extract them to a gem.

Comment: okay... But how do I include the class? What is config.root? I dont see config.autoload_paths in my application.rb file. I see `  # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de` and `require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)`.. I'm using rails 4 btw. What should I do?

Comment: Add the `config.autoload_paths` line from this answer into `class Application < Rails::Application` in your `config/application.rb` file. This causes Rails to autoload the class, and you should be able to instantiate it just like you do in your question.

Comment: Got it! It works. thanks. SO I have another question. I'm creating an instance of this class in my controller. Would every controller request create a new instance of that regular ruby class? Just want to make sure the regular ruby class's instance properties are not going to be shared across requests. Thanks.

Comment: @TazMan, yes, every request will get a new instance of the class. In fact, every request gets a new instance of a controller as well - most of the classes you add to your Rails app yourself (models, controllers, etc) are instantiated per request.